# Use "Post-test script" to fail build

Tags: build-definition

Is there anyway to fail the build from a Post-test PowerShell script?

I tried throwing an exception within the PS script but it doesn't fail the build.

Comment: try setting the exit code to something other than 1.

Comment: Tried ending PS script with "exit 0" and the build succeeded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you need to return a value *lower* than 0. Try `exit -1`

Comment: Is this documented somewhere? Could you provide a link?